# How to populate data in a form by assigning query results to textbox using VBA code

Tags: sql, ms-access

I ran into a problem with populating data in access form.

Currently my table designs are: One table **[product]** for all the product information (ID, Prodname); one **[product level data]** for a list of product level variants (ID, variant); and one table **[product level data update]** for updating the values of these variants (ID, ProdID, VariantID, update value, timestamp). So the variants are time sensitive.

Now, I want to create a [form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5wFm6.png) that includes all those variant values subjective to time. So, for example, if I enter a purchase time X, then it will populate the form with the last updated values for all variants for the product at time X.

I know how to populate one textbox with the following query:

```
Select Top 1 updatevalue
From table [product level data update]
Where prodID = A 
And variantID = [forms]![form name]![detailID]
And timestamp <= [forms]![form name]![purchase time]
Order by timestamp
```

But since access form only allows one data source for a form, I don't know how to populate all the data I need in the form in this way.

Hope it makes sense! I am quite a newbie, so hopefully someone more experienced can give me a hint on this questions.

Appreciate any help!

---

update to my question:

So I thought hard about this, since I need to run a query for each variant, I can't set the control source of the form to one query. Instead, I can write a VBA code to assign the results from queries to each textbox.

So I start writing this code...and I can't get it to work. Here is my code below:

```
Private Sub purchasedate_AfterUpdate()

Dim theminimum As String
Dim thedataID As String
Dim theprodscID As String
Dim thepurchasedate As String


thedataID = "1"
theprodscID = Me.prodscID.Value
thepurchasedate = Me.purchasedate.Value

theminimum = "Select Top 1 [update value]" & _
            "From [product and shareclass level data update]" & _
            " Where [product and shareclass level data update].[dataID] = thedataID" & _
            " And [product and shareclass level data update].[prodscID] = theprodscID" & _
            " And [product and shareclass level data update].[timestamp] <= thepurchasedate" & _
            " Order by [product and shareclass level data update].[timestamp] DESC"


Me.minimum.SetFocus
Me.minimum = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("theminimum").Fields(0).Value

End Sub
```

The Error message is that "Access can't find the table or query "theminimum""... Am I missing something on the query expression?

Comment: You need to show some examples of the query SQL you have created and why they're not doing what you want. Show what they do. Show what they should look like. Your description won't get many solutions as it is.

Comment: @dbmitch, thanks, I will edit my question